# How do I link Vertex Groups to Bones?

Tags: armature, bones, vertex-groups

I watched all the youtube tutorials and all the questions asked here and I still can't get it to work.
I did the vertex groups, I created the bones, I weightpainted, I added armature modifiers, used the same name, and it still doesn't work.

[image: Armature settings]

Here is the download link: https://we.tl/t-ZJBYjOxbOJ.

Comment: vertex groups must have the same name as the bones, but first, why do you create several armatures? Create one with several bones in it

Comment: the name of vertex groups are names of the bones, not the names of the armatures.